# Python pandas multiple identical table data packets join, how?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, join

as basic information we have two Tables with different data divided in smaller csv packages. The Tables has 2x2 Join keys.

Table 1 is divided into 3..to n smaller csv packages.   // Concatination/ Appending is not an option
Table 2 is also divided into 3 ... to n smaller csv packages.    // same as above

TABLE 1 package 1 ..n
Child_PID, Data1, Data2, Parent_PID, Data1, Data2

Table 2 package 1....n
CQ_PID, XTX_ID_, OS_PID, Time

Problems:

i want to join Table 2 package 1 with table 1 package 1,2...n  (all finde)

when i join table 2 package 2 with table 1 package 1...n

if the first join is done there exist the new columns

```
table1Package1= pd.merge(table1Package1, table2Package1, how='left', left_on='Child_PID', right_on='OS_PID')
```

1. First problem if i want to do a second left join table 1 package 1 with table 2 package 2
   the new columns already exist so python create new columns and rename the old ones X_Time, Y_Time
   (My wish is that instead of new Columns fill up the empty joined rows if there is a join match)
2. I HAve multiple joins on these 2 tables But i only want to add 2 columns from the second table x2 times

TABLE 1 package 1 ..n   (short T1p1 for table 1 package 1)
Child_PID, Data1, Data2, Parent_PID, Data1, Data2

Table 2 package 1....n (short T2p1 for table 2 package 1)
CQ_PID, XTX_ID_, OS_PID, Time

Table 1 and package n is always the root table and the result table

i want to join  Child_PID with OS_PID  new columns on t1p1 = XTX_ID, TIME
i want to join Parent_PID with OS_PID  new columns on t1p1 = Parent_XTX_ID, Parent_TIME

if in t2p1 OS_PID is empty then join with CQ_PID instead of OS_PID and do the same steps and above

Summarize:
how to handle 2nd 3rd join to fill up gaps
how to make the same join with parent columns
how to alternative join with another field if OS_PID is empty

i know its complex but i hope you understand my problem

Comment: It would be nice if you add some pictures of the tables. Some people are more understand more with graphics than other